# Why isn't config.cache_classes = false working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, redmine

I'm new to RoR and currently need to develop a plugin for redmine (which is not the issue so far). Therefore I setup ruby 1.8.7, redmine 1.0.5 and radrails 2. The ruby interpreter is set as default in radrails and I can also start/stop the redmine server (mongrel, webrick, lightTPD - all work fine).

The problem that I'm really crashing on is that I don't get the "config.cache_classes = false" to work (development environment is set). So I always have to restart the server when I saved sth. - and this is very annoying :(

Btw. I have to admit that I'm trying this on windows...

Thanks in advance,
Christan

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't reload classes in plugins (vendor/plugins). So even though it's reloading the app/ classes, it's keeping around your older versions until you restart the server.

I have a script I use with passenger in developer that watches for changes in vendor/plugins and restart passenger automatically.

http://theadmin.org/articles/2010/06/17/rails-plugin-reloading-with-passenger/

Comment: Thank you very much for that hint. Meanwhile I switched to Ubuntu on a VM with passenger - Windows+RoR was no good mixture at all. Then I wrote a Ruble for AptanaStudio that touched the restart.txt after saving a file - but this threw errors and now it doesn't even work anymore (Seems like they have deleted my post on theyr support platform :/) Now I'll the solution you suggest - thank you!

Comment: Got it up and running - btw. there is a gem:

`gem install sinefunc-rstakeout`

As I'm quite new to linux (ubuntu) maybe this is a stupid question but: Do you know a trick, how I can run this in background (eventually even starting and shutting down with aptana)? Thanks a lot..